# Consulting two databases and three tables (Entity Framework, SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jqgrid

I'm working on a MVC .NET application using EF.
I have a JqGrid in my view which works correctly bringing data from one table, but the information that I need is in two databases and three tables (Database is not normalized correctly, it sucks). I already have my two context (edmx) created in my project, I just had no idea on how to proceed in my Model. Here is my query which works fine in SQL Server

```
SELECT  
    a.idPlanta, a.idArticulo, b.DescripcionCorta, c.Planta, 
    a.FechaAlta, a.Existencia
FROM 
    CAT_ArticulosEnPlanta AS a 
INNER JOIN
    CAT_Articulos AS b ON a.idArticulo = b.idArticulo
INNER JOIN 
    [LEC].[dbo].[Plantas] AS c ON a.idPlanta = c.PlantaID
ORDER BY 
    b.DescripcionCorta ASC;
```

and here is my model that brings information from one table

```
public List<ArticulosPlantaView> GetArticulosEnPlanta()
{  
        List<ArticulosPlantaView> articuloss = new List<ArticulosPlantaView>();

        using (TemakaSoftTestEntities TSTE = new TemakaSoftTestEntities())
        {
            ArticulosPlantaView APV;

            foreach (CAT_ArticulosEnPlanta a in TSTE.CAT_ArticulosEnPlanta)
            {
                APV = new ArticulosPlantaView();
                APV.idArticulo = a.idArticulo;
                APV.idPlanta = a.idPlanta;
                APV.idUsuarioAlta = a.idUsuarioAlta;
                APV.FechaAlta = a.FechaAlta;
                APV.Existencia = a.Existencia;
                APV.Comentarios = a.Comentarios;
                APV.idUsuarioElimina = a.idUsuarioElimina;
                APV.FechaEliminacion = a.FechaEliminacion;
                APV.Visible = a.Visible;

                articuloss.Add(APV);
            }
            return articuloss;
        }
}

public ArticulosPlantaDataView GetArticulosPlantaDataView()
{
        ArticulosPlantaDataView APDV = new ArticulosPlantaDataView();
        List<ArticulosPlantaView> articuloss = GetArticulosEnPlanta();
        APDV.articulos = articuloss;
        return APDV;
}
```

An example will help a lot.

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Comment: One approach is to define a [synonym](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) so you can address all tables in one context class because they're in one database (sort of).

Comment: By the way, just a little advice.  You're showing a lot of code that doesn't really matter for the question you're asking. Try to reduce it to the code that does matter and als try to ask your question more clearly (*I just need to implement my query...* tells what you want, not which particular problem you're struggling with).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @GertArnold thank you for your advice, actually you're right. Maybe can you help me with an example of how to implement the query?

Comment: @marc_s thank you, but I would prefer an example of how to implement the query with EF.??

Comment: In fact the only code that matters is: the context and the classes. But as long as one class is mapped to a second database (and, hence, in a second context) you won't be able to combine them in one EF LINQ query.